# Nested radical implementation

Tags: iteration, nested-function

I am attempting to code
$$F(x,n)=\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+2\sqrt{x+\cdots +n\sqrt{x}}}}.$$
For example,
$$F(x,1)=\sqrt{x+\sqrt x},$$
$$F(x,2)=\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+2\sqrt x}},$$
and so on. I found the `Nest` and `Fold` functions which seem to be what I need. I tried this but it wasn't quite right.

```
f[n_, a_] := Sqrt[x + n a] 
F[x_, n_] := Fold[f, x, Table[m, {m, n, 1, -1}]]
```

$$F(x,8)=\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+2 \sqrt{x+3 \sqrt{x+4 \sqrt{x+5 \sqrt{x+6    \sqrt{x+21 \sqrt{x}}}}}}}}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With:

```
F[x_, n0_] := Module[{n = n0}, Nest[Sqrt[x + n--  #] &, Sqrt@x, n]];
```

E.g.:

```
F[x, 6]
```

[image]

P.S. Try do submit a really simple short question, that you delete afterwards, to find out what goes wrong.

Comment: I tried removing everything from the question except the first few words and still it would not let me submit saying there is an error with my code...very strange indeed.

Answer (score 4):

**Using `Fold`:**

```
n = 6;
f[x_, n_] := Sqrt@Fold[x + #2 Sqrt[#1] &, x, Range[n, 1, -1]];
```

Example:

```
f[x, 6]

TraditionalForm@f[x, 6]
```

$\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+2 \sqrt{x+3 \sqrt{x+4 \sqrt{x+5 \sqrt{x+6 \sqrt{x}}}}}}}$